# how do I create the several zip files no larger than 50 MB?

Tags: python, zip

I'm making a bot on pytelegrambotapi and I get a zip file with a video from users. I need to process the video and archive the video into a zip file, but I can send files in telegram up to 50 MB. Therefore, I need to create, if necessary, several ZIP files up to 50 MB. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my implementation to the problem:

```
#zipfile module for handeling zip files
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os

def create_zip_files(zip_name, converting_file_path: list, max_size=50):
    # create a ZipFile object


    #create every file in zip
    last_element = None
    num_zib_files = 1

    files_writting = True
    while files_writting:
        zipObj = ZipFile(zip_name + str(num_zib_files) + '.zip', 'w')
        for e in converting_file_path:
            if round(os.path.getsize(zip_name + str(num_zib_files) + '.zip') / 1e6) + round(os.path.getsize(e) / 1e6) < max_size:
                last_element = e
                zipObj.write(e)
            else:
                num_zib_files += 1
                zipObj.close()
                zipObj = ZipFile(zip_name + str(num_zib_files) + '.zip', 'w')
        break

    #close the file
    zipObj.close()


#example:
lst = []
for i in range(0, 20):
    num_str = str(i)
    lst.append('out' + num_str + '.txt')
    print(lst)

create_zip_files('rec', lst)
```